Can the role of the Fed to manage the money supply be decentralized?
With the incoming administration hinting at reforming the federal reserve, I’ve been wondering is there a way to make a globally accessible and fairer way to manage monetary policy?
There’s an old project from 2019, called Ampleforth that created something like this. It’s designed to expand and contract the monetary supply automatically with supply and demand as opposed to how the fed changes the supply with interest rates and OMOs.
I found an article that talks about several economic theories and seems to hint that this could work looking at it from an Austrian and behavioral economics perspective, as well as Monetarism which advocates for a stable currency and a Post Keynesian perspective which supports the idea of the supply of currency should respond to demand.
I’m curious to hear from those that have studied economics or have a better grasp of these concepts then I do, can this work? What are the pitfalls here? Have we tried anything like this in history before?
Here’s the article. The first half talks about the cryptocurrency but if you are curious about the economics skip down to “Sound Economic Money”.
https://guz-massadoption.medium.com/elastic-economics-the-cryptocurrency-that-breathes-b94cd3420c42

The May 2022 collapse of the Terra / LUNA cryptocurrencies may be discouraging for those aiming to ensure stability through algorithms.
